# Retrofit with recyclerview issue

Tags: android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am not getting data in recycler view but not getting any error .
This is Main Activity class

```
package in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.activity;    
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;    
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;    
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.AppController;
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.R;
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.adepter.CarTypeAdepter;
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.helper.ToastHelper;
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model.Cartype;
import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model.CartypeArray;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;    
public class Slect_Car_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    RecyclerView rvGetCartype;
    private ArrayList<Cartype> data;
    private CarTypeAdepter carTypeAdepter;
    private TextView txt_data;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slect__car_);
        rvGetCartype = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RV_list);
        txt_data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_data);
        getAndSetCarType();   
    }    
    private void getAndSetCarType() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
        progressDialog.show();
        Call<CartypeArray> call = AppController.getInstance().getApiInterface().getCartype();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CartypeArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CartypeArray> call, Response<CartypeArray> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                CartypeArray cartypeArray = response.body();      

                Collections.reverse(cartypeArray.getCtypes());
                carTypeAdepter = new CarTypeAdepter(cartypeArray,getApplicationContext());

                rvGetCartype.setAdapter(carTypeAdepter);   

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CartypeArray> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

    }
}
```

This is my model class for retrofit which gives Json array with status

```
 package in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model;        
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;       

    public class Cartype {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private String id;

        @SerializedName("vehicle_type")
        @Expose
        private String Vehicale_type;

        @SerializedName("vehicle_name")
        @Expose
        private String Vehicale_name;

        @SerializedName("vehicle_no")
        @Expose
        private String Vehicale_no;

        @SerializedName("vimage")
        @Expose
        private String Vimage;

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        @Expose
        private String created_at;

        @SerializedName("updated_at")
        @Expose
        private String updated_at;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getVehicale_type() {
            return Vehicale_type;
        }

        public void setVehicale_type(String vehicale_type) {
            Vehicale_type = vehicale_type;
        }

        public String getVehicale_name() {
            return Vehicale_name;
        }

        public void setVehicale_name(String vehicale_name) {
            Vehicale_name = vehicale_name;
        }

        public String getVehicale_no() {
            return Vehicale_no;
        }

        public void setVehicale_no(String vehicale_no) {
            Vehicale_no = vehicale_no;
        }

        public String getVimage() {
            return Vimage;
        }

        public void setVimage(String vimage) {
            Vimage = vimage;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getCreated_at() {
            return created_at;
        }

        public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
            this.created_at = created_at;
        }

        public String getUpdated_at() {
            return updated_at;
        }

        public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
            this.updated_at = updated_at;
        }
    }
```

This is my Adapter class with view holder for recycler view

```
   package in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.adepter;        
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;        
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;        
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.R;
    import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model.Cartype;
    import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model.CartypeArray;
    import in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.utils.Constans;       



    public class CarTypeAdepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private CartypeArray cartypeArray;
        private Context mcontext;



        public CarTypeAdepter(CartypeArray cartypeArray, Context mcontext) {
            this.cartypeArray = cartypeArray;
            this.mcontext = mcontext;
        }        

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = (LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_car,parent, false));
            CartypeHolder cartypeHolder = new CartypeHolder(view);
            return cartypeHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder Holder, int position) {
            CartypeHolder cartypeHolder = (CartypeHolder) Holder;

            cartypeHolder.txt_cartype.setText(cartypeArray.getCtypes().get(position).getVehicale_name());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cartypeArray.getCtypes().size();
        }

        private class CartypeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView img_car;
            TextView txt_cartype;
            public CartypeHolder(View itemview) {
                super(itemview);
                img_car = (ImageView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.CarImageView);
                txt_cartype = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            }
        }
    }
```

My second model class for retrofit  for getting JSON data

```
   package in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.model;

    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;        
    import java.util.List;       


    public class CartypeArray {      

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private Boolean status;
        @SerializedName("Cartype")
        @Expose
        private List<Cartype> ctypes;

        public Boolean getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
            this.status = status;
        }



        public List<Cartype> getCtypes() {
            return ctypes;
        }

        public void setCtypes(List<Cartype> ctypes) {
            this.ctypes = ctypes;
        }
    }
```

This is Activity main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"        tools:context="in.co.getonlinerecharge.cab.bw_cab.activity.Slect_Car_Activity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Select Your Car" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RV_list"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txt_data"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

List of display data for list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >    
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/CarImageView"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/suv"
                    />    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        android:text="SUV"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/card_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Layout Manager to your recycler in onCreate:

```
rvGetCartype = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RV_list);
rvGetCartype.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

If it didnt help try next:
1.Make sure, that in your response ArrayList isnt empty.

2.If it isnt, try to next:

```
public class CarTypeAdepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Cartype> cartypeArray;
    private Context mcontext;
    public CarTypeAdapter(Context context){
        this.mcontext = context;
        cartypeArray = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void setList(ArrayList<Cartype> list){
        this. cartypeArray = list;
        notifyDataSetChanges();
    }
//other methods
}
```

then create variable of this adapter in activity and init it in onCreate, and set it to your recycler view. Then in onResponse use method setList(cartypeArray) to set array to adapter.

Hope you understand me and its help.